# SSH continue to ask for password prompt

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I appreciate this is a recurring question, but I'm really struggling to get my SSH connection password-less irrespective of the many threads and changes I've done so far.
I do remember this was once used to work fine.

**On my local Mac (Catalina)**

- my keys are in the ~.ssh folder which has permissions set to 700
- files have 600 permission
- everything is own by my user

I have also created a config file as

```
Host MyRemoteHost
HostName 181.12.14.123
User myself
PasswordAuthentication no
PreferredAuthentications=publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**On the remote server, Ubuntu**

- the pub key is in the ~.ssh/authorized_keys
- permission on the above is 600
- I've amended the ssh_config file in /etc/ssh by adding a `PreferredAuthentications publickey,password` as I thought it was the only bit missing, although here the file is owned by the root user.

Just in case I have re-created the local RSA key using a 4096 bytes length.

When SSH in verbose mode, I can ultimately see the private key mode is used, but I was remembering/expecting for a no password prompt at all.

Am I wrong?

Comment: `PasswordAuthentication no` should be in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file inside the remote Ubuntu server. Not in the local Mac. Same goes for `PreferredAuthentications=publickey`.

Comment: Note the difference between `ssh_config` and `sshd_config`. The second one is for configuring the ssh server.

Comment: Are you being asked for a pass*word*, or for a pass*phrase* to unlock the key?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm asked for a passphrase to unlock the key now that I noticed. So I guess this is somehow normal. I was puzzled because I was trying to play with rsync to update a site, but all the time I'm asked for the passphrase

Comment: @user68186 PasswordAuthentication is already in the sshd_config file set to no. The PreferredAuthentication though I felt it was necessary in the ssh_config but thinking to this, it doesn't make sense. Should that go with the = to specify the value? I can see all the other settings without it.

Comment: @AndreaMoro you can either create a key with an empty passphrase, or use a keychain manager on your local system so that you only need to unlock the SSH key once per session - how exactly to do that is off-topic here; see for example [How to use Mac OS X Keychain with SSH keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/88470/how-to-use-mac-os-x-keychain-with-ssh-keys)

Comment: I agree with @steeldriver. This question is not about the remote Ubuntu password. It is about the private key passphrase management in the local Mac computer. If this is not true, please update the question with the new information. Otherwise I vote to close this question as being not about Ubuntu.

Comment: I believe you are right guys. Thanks for putting on the right direction.